# Sound clips not working in LiveCode

Tags: audio, livecode

I can't get any audio clips to play in LiveCode apps.

I'm using `wav files`, which are supposed to work in LiveCode, and I followed these [instructions](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4071/l/25230-play-sounds)

For instance, I tried:

```
    on mouseUp
    play audioClip `path/filename.wav`
    end mouseUp
```

I also imported the clip (import as control), then used this code:

```
on mouseUp
play "filename.wav"
end mouseUp
```

I tried these steps with several clips, all of which play just fine outside of LiveCode.

Clicking the button has an effect -- it keeps you from doing anything else (i.e. clicking another button) for the length of the clip -- but you can't actually hear the sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond to your two examples in reverse order.

The second example looks perfect, and should work. Make sure you have double checked the spelling of the name of the imported audio clip. Also make sure you are using the latest stable release of LiveCode. (I tested it just now in v. 7.0.3 on Mac.) There have been a few bugs recently with audio playback that crept into some of the beta releases, which have since been fixed.

The first example has a couple of potential problems. First, you are using the wrong characters for quoting the relative file path, but that may have just been a typing error when you entered your question. Use double quotes instead:

```
play "path/filename.wav" -- "audioClip" is optional
```

Second, you are using a relative file path. This will only work if you have previously set the defaultFolder property to the folder containing your .wav file.

```
set the defaultFolder to "/path/to/folder"
play "path/filename.wave"
```

Or you could use an absolute path:

```
play "/path/to/folder/path/filename/wav"
```

Comment: When importing sound LiveCode do support WAV but not all sample rates. At least no in my experience, 16-bit, 44 kHz should work, but other sample rates might not work...

Comment: Thanks, Devin and hliljegren. As you guessed, the single quotation marks were a typing error -- I did have it right in the actual code (and I used an absolute path). What I discovered: The problem appears to be PC-based -- or perhaps just my PC. I tried the stack on a Mac, and the sounds played.